# Dados passados via function

Tags: php, mysql

Criei uma `function` para cadastrar imagens que até ontem as 18:00 funcionava normalmente e hoje pela manhã os dados do `form` não estão sendo passados.
por incrível que pareça ninguém mexeu no código.

```
<?php //Chama a função inserir caso tenha algum dado em POST (includes/conexao)
if (isset($_POST['salvar'])) {
    criar_album('albumImagens', 'capa', $_POST);
}  
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
  <fieldset>

    <legend>Nova imagem</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="nome">Nome</label>  
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input --> 
    <div class="form-group">   
      <div id="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="capa">Capa:</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" name="capa" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="imagem">Album:</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="form-control" required multiple>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="salvar"></label>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <button name="salvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Para verificar se os dados estavam sendo passados eu fiz;

```
function criar_album($album, $destaque, $dados){
    $con = conectar();
    var_dump($dados); 
    die();
}
```

E o único dado passado é o primeiro input `nome`.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Já verificou os logs de erro da sua aplicação/servidor?

Comment: Debug o $_POST. Veja quais são os dados que vem no method post.

No seu formulário, você está usando class. Por que não usar name? Acho que esta questão de id e class são usados, muitas vezes, sem necessidade. Se você usar name, você tem mais sucesso de restaurá-lo o que é passado no $_POST. É o que eu acho e, por questão de lógica, você deve passar, além do label, o name daquele campo no formulário. Isso evita até erro ao salvar no banco. Não sei se estou correto ou se estou trocando algum conceito.

Comment: @AndréNascimento a class e id não interferem em nada, e como coloquei no post eu fiz o `var_dump` para saber o que estava sendo passado via post e só o input `nome` esta sendo passado.

Comment: @Rafael Acioly

O ideal seria rever o código do form e, até para testar se quiser, coloque o atributo name. E debug novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se o método do form for POST, para inputs do tipo file use $_FILES ao invés de $_POST

```
<?php 
//Chama a função inserir caso tenha algum dado em POST  (includes/conexao)
if (isset($_POST['salvar'])) {
    print_r($_FILES);
}  
?>
```

Teste também modificando o método do form para GET

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['salvar'])) {
        print_r($_GET);
 } 
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
  <fieldset> ....
....
```